# QScopedPointer vs parent

Tags: qt, qscopedpointer

I need some explanation about the next situation. Assume we have the next code:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{ 
    public:
    MyClass(QObject* parent = nullptr)
    {
        m_member.reset(new QObject(this));
    }
    ~MyClass(){} override;
    private: 
    QScopedPointer< QObject> m_member;
};
```

I can't understand if it's safe to pass an object with a parent to QScopedPointer. Might it be any situation when the object is deleted twice by the parent and by the smart pointer and it will lead to a crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destruction of QObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730330/destruction-of-qobjects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely safe. Here is what happens when an instance of `MyClass` gets destroyed:

1. `MyClass`'s destructor gets called (which does nothing in your example)
2. all member variables of `MyClass` get destructed. In your case, `QScopedPointer`'s destructor gets called, which means that the child `QObject` is deleted. When a `QObject` is destroyed it is [removed from its parent's list of children](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects), so the parent no longer tries to delete this `QObject`
3. `QObject`'s destructor for your `MyClass` instance gets called and it sees no children to delete

You may also want to consider holding your child member `QObject` by value if there is no reason to allocate it dynamically

Comment: Thanx a lot for your explanation!